NewsLetter Animation in Gmail
I've created a simple HTML and CSS page with a small animation, but the issue is that the animation isn't displaying in Gmail. Can you suggest some solutions for it to display?
Such as hosting the CSS file and then integrating it into the HTML file, or hosting the entire newsletter.
Thanks in advance.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cool Text Animation</title>
  <style>
    @keyframes coolAnimation {
      0%,
      25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100%);
      }
      12.5% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }
    
    #textContainer {
      position: relative;
      roverflow: hidden;
      /* Cacher tout débordement */
    }
    
    .coolText {
      color: #000000;
      font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 40px;
      animation: coolAnimation 12s ease-in-out infinite;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(100%);
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    
    .coolText:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 9s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="textContainer">
    <h3 class="coolText"> UTULISATION <br>ILLIMITEÉ </h3>
    <h3 class="coolText"> SANS <br>CONTACT </h3>
    <h3 class="coolText">SANS <br>ABONNEMENT</h3>
    <h3 class="coolText">ECO- <br> RESPONSABLE</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



